# how to show data from two database tables in vue with vuetify

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a list of clients wiht a salesman field which is bound to a user id in the database, ¿how do i show in the table the user name that corresponds to its id?

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="arrayClientes">
  <template v-slot:item.user_id="{ item }" :items="userLists">
          <span>{{item.user_id}}</span>
  </template>
```

Script:

```
computed: {  
      userLists() {
        return this.$store.state.user.users;
      },
    },
    created(){
        this.$store.dispatch('user/getUsers')
    },
```

Comment: Hello Hector, welcome to stack. To make it easier to answer your question can you share the data scheme for the `user` object and what the `$store.dispatch()` function looks like. Can you also explain what happens if you simply change the span to  ` <span>item.username}}</span>` assuming username is part of your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a method, which filters the specific user id and returns the user object.

For example:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    getUser(id) {
      return this.userLists.filter((user) => user.id === id))[0];
    },
  },
};
```

After that you can simply call this method in your span tag and specify the user id as a parameter.

Note: this does not check if the user id exists in the users list.

Comment: Thanks it worked as you showed. In addition, do yo know how can instead of returning the whole object just return an specific property of the object? Im trying to achieve to show the property "name"  which is a string

Comment: Yeah you can just access the username for that user (if it exists in the object) by doing getUser(123).username or directly in the method ...[0].username

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way

```
getUser(id) {
     return this.userLists.filter(user => user.id === id).map(user => user.name)[0];
},
```

I hope it works for you, regards!